# How to set IP address to an existing SOCKET

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I know I can get the IP address by using 'getpeername' function, but how can I set the IP address to an existing socket? I search the web and I only find that it can be done by creating a new socket. From MSDN example, it shows the same client socket can be used to receive and send, but what can I do with a different IP.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a socket towards a specific IP address or port you need to bind the socket.

More information about the bind function can be found here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396